# Use column name instead of a number to return a value in the VLOOKUP function using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I've managed to write a Vlookup function that works perfectly across multiple sheets using VBA.

However, I have to deal with new workbooks weekly so I'm having to slightly alter my code to ensure the Vlookup in my macro pulls data from the correct columns as these can change.

My code is:

```
Set my_sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 
Set my_sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 

last_row = my_sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
last_row1 = my_sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set dataRange = my_sheet2.Range("A2:BA" & last_row1) '//range for data in second worksheet that Vlookup will use to locate third column

On Error Resume Next

  For x = 2 To last_row1

  my_sheet1.Range("D" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(my_sheet1.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRange, 3, 0) 

  Next x
```

So this VLOOKUP pulls data from Column 3 ("Worker_Name") in Sheet2 into Column D on Sheet1.

Is it possible to use "Worker_Name" instead of 3 in my VLOOKUP? Or do I have to use another function such as MATCH?

Comment: Have you tried converting the sheet to a `ListObject` first? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects.add

Comment: When you say "column name", are you referring to a named range assigned to a column (eg., `=mySheet!$E:$E`)?  ...like, it shows up in the Name Manager? (which btw, you can open with `CTRL`+`F3`)  ...and if so, you're trying to get the column number that the named range refers to, if I'm understanding correctly?  If that's right, you could use `range("myNamedRange").Column`

Comment: @braX Not sure what you mean by converting the sheet to a ListObject? I'm new to VBA so still figuring things out. This is only a small snippet of my code, I have previously dimmed my variables as Range's, Worksheet's and Long's if that's what you meant?

Comment: @ashleedawg Apologies I should've been more specific. Column name is just the value of cells I have inputted in the top row...e.g., Worker_Name, Address, Salary etc. My problem is that I receive new worksheets every week and these column names could be in different columns. For example Worker_Name might be in column 3 one week and column 5 the next, so my VLOOKUP won't pull what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Match()`

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim my_sheet1 As Worksheet, my_sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim last_row1 As Long, last_row2 As Long, x As Long
    Dim DataRange As Range, colHeader As String, m, res
    
    Set my_sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set my_sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    last_row1 = my_sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    last_row2 = my_sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set DataRange = my_sheet2.Range("A2:BA" & last_row2)
    
    colHeader = "Worker_Name"  'column to return results from
    
    'find the column position
    m = Application.Match(colHeader, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
    
    If Not IsError(m) Then      'got a match?
        For x = 2 To last_row1
            'use the found column
            res = Application.VLookup(my_sheet1.Range("A" & x).Value, DataRange, m, False)
            my_sheet1.Range("D" & x).Value = IIf(IsError(res), "", res) 'check for no match
        Next x
    Else
        MsgBox "Column header '" & colHeader & "' not found", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```